# Focus the camera on an object using focusMode on WebRTC

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, getusermedia, mediastream

I'm trying to get the camera to focus on an object, by using `focusMode` on the stream track received from `getUserMedia`. But after changing the property of focus mode to `manual` mode, I don't see it reflect on the stream also I could see that after applying `focusMode` constraint it stays unchanged(`focusMode: continuous`). The issue is when I capture an image, using the stream, the image is blurry because of lack of focus.

Here is a code snippet.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then((stream) => {
          video.srcObject = stream;
          track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
          track.applyConstraints({
            advanced: [
              { focusMode: 'manual', focusDistance: 0.33 }
            ]
          })
        });
```

Does anybody have experience with getting the camera to focus using the `manual` or `single-shot` mode? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It clears up you do have a camera where `track.getSettings()` reveal support for *focusMode*. I'm not seeing that on mine, so I guess I either don't have the right camera, or don't know how to turn on this feature, so I probably won't be much help—Have you tried `track.applyConstraints({focusMode: 'manual', focusDistance: 0.33})`?

Comment: Seems like this has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649030/changing-focusmode-not-working-using-mediastream-api-in-google-chrome). No solution though.